# Why won't my page load

Tags: asp.net, html, asp-classic

I have a net 2.0 ASP page with an HTML form that connects to a MS SQL 2008 database. I thought it was the connection string that was the problem when my page would not load,but with some  help from this site and others, I beleive the connection is being made but the form just isn't loading.  I am not an experienced ASP or HTML coder and  I am learning as I go.  I don't seem to get any errors in my Firefox or IE browser, and either I am not looking in the correct log, or the IIS is not giving me any errors either. The page just never loads.  Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide some ASP code?

Comment: Did you try running the debugger?

Comment: What you see, what the error code ?

Comment: Are you running any "security tools", like Norton Antivirus, Norton Internet Security, Symantec ..., etc? Are you doing any file system access using the FileSystemObject?

Comment: Why don't you create a console app and check whether you can query the database using the same code you have in you asp.net page or just put a breakpoint at the start of you page load event handler and step through the code.

Comment: I guess the first good question to ask is, do you have access to the code which generates this page? Second would be, do any other pages from the same project load? Third, are you seeing any type of error (usually .net pages will have ugly yellow and red error pages)? Fourth, just what is the page supposed to do, does it load data to display, or does it submit data to the database?

Answer (score 1):

@Tomas - Thanks for the help.  I have my connection working now. One thing it turns out my pages are ASP.NET 2.0 and my web was configured for ASP.NET 4.0. Once I fixed that I was able to connect. Then I got login failures but once I had my password reset correctly, I was able to get in and insert a new record. I am still having issues with having to restart ISS after some web pages try to load, but at least it is progress.

@ Carlos - To tell you the truth I have no idea what the difference is. I am just trying to fix a page that someone else wrote in 2006 and now it needs to be moved to a brand new server (64 bit) and upgraded from SQL 2000 to SQL 2008. I got the job because I am the only tech on site who had any experience with SQL and a little HTML experience.

The connection string that works is "Provider=SQLNCLI10;Server=server/instance;Database=dbname;Integrated Security=SSPI;"

At least now I know my connection and the database work and I can move on to the IIS problem.

@Everyone - Thanks so much for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Check EventViewer for errors. Run your application in debug mode, with CLR Exceptions enabled (go to Debug->Exceptions, check Common Language Runtime Exceptions in Thrown column) and you will see if application is throwing any exceptions.

Check http://forums.asp.net/t/1046374.aspx, maybe it will provide some help.

Sidenote: why you are not using standard asp.net connectors to sql instead of odbc?

Answer (score 0):

Is your page ASP or ASP.NET? I am confussed since you have tagged both.

If your are triying to connect from ASP.NET to MS SQL Server then the ODBC connector is not recommended. You should be using the [.NET Framework Data Provider for SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a6cd7c08%28v=VS.80%29.aspx). Click on it so you can have a better understading of the way to connect to SQL Server.